# valgrind invalid write of size 4

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can I fix this problem, my program is doing fine, but valgrind keeps telling me that I am making mistakes.

**Code**
[image]

**Errors**
[image]

I cant figure out what is wrong in lines 104 and 11

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a **[MCVE]**."_

Comment: Quit using `new[]` and use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you pasted the code in (with nice indentation) instead of a picture.   Either way, the problem seems to be that you are decrementing j aside from the for loop.

```
for(int j=v[z]-1;j>=0;j--) {
    for (int g=max_el;g > 0;g--) {  // secondary problem.
        p[k][j] = g;
        j--;                // This is the problem.
    }
}
```

Maybe this instead :

```
for(int j=v[z]-1;j>=0;j--) {
    int g=max_el;
    p[k][j] = g;
    --g;
}
```

Hard to tell without the data, but it looks like you are decrementing j without considering the limits j must be >= 0.  You could certainly try to debug this using a debugger, but I suspect that simply printing indexes as you loop through would shine a light onto some issues.